# Is LONG_MAX -1 in 64bit machine?

Tags: c, types, numbers

I found that LONG_MAX (9223372036854775807) is actually saved as below on the long type variable in the 64-bit machine.

```
Hex: 0xffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff

Bin: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

As I know, the most significant bit is used as a signed bit.

And the 9223372036854775807 is changed as below in the Windows calculator.

```
Hex: 0x7fff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
Bin: 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

So, IMHO, the LONG_MAX should be saved as below

```
Hex: 0x7fff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
Bin: 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Is a long variable considered as an unsigned value?

I noticed somebody ask how I found that situation.

I found the situation in the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        long a;

        a = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0); 

        printf("%ld\n", a); 

        return 0;
}
```

Actually, I didn't use the LONG_MAX macro, but when I execute the program, I used 9223372036854775807 value statically.

I checked the value is safe as a 0x7fff ... with gdb like below

```
Reading symbols from test...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40055c: file test.c, line 8.
(gdb) r 9223372036854775807
Starting program: ./test 9223372036854775807

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe308) at test.c:8
8       a = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
(gdb) n
10      printf("%ld\n", a);
(gdb) x/gt &a
0x7fffffffe218: 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
(gdb)
```

Even though I didn't use the LONG_MAX macro, the value 9223372036854775807 is the same as the LONG_MAX macro.

So, I think it should be saved as a 0x7fff ... like using LONG_MAX.

Comment: Where did you find that? BW: You have some excess `ffff` in your numbers.

Comment: 9223372036854775807 is 0x7fffffffffffffff. The all-ff unsigned value would be 18446744073709551615.

Comment: It's `0xffff ffff ffff ffff`, not `0xffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff` etc.

Comment: @dratenik, that would be `unsigned long`, assuming the implementation has 64 bit `long` types

Comment: @JackLilhammers I added the code I found in that situation. Did I make some mistakes?

Comment: @JackLilhammers yes, the error was indeed elsewhere, see my answer.

Comment: In case you are a beginner learning C, always compile with `-std=c11 -pedantic -Werror -Wall -Wextra`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`, therefore your compiler issued a warning such as `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strtol’`.

As you chose to ignore the warning, the compiler simply considered the return value of `strtol` as `int` (32 bit value) instead of `long` (64 bit value), therefore a truncation from 64 bit to 32 bit occurs, hence the difference.

Demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        long a, b;
        a = strtol("9223372036854775807", NULL, 0); 
        b = LONG_MAX;
        printf("%ld %ld\n", a, b); 
}
```

Run this with and whithout uncommenting `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Conclusion: always consider warnings containing the word "implicit" as errors.

Comment: Thank you very much! But there was no error and warning  in my gcc whose version is 4.8.5-4ubuntu8.

Comment: @JoontaekOh gcc 4.8.5 is very old and this warning is not enabled by default. Compile with the `-Wall` option or even better install a more recent version of gcc. The current version is 10.2 (I think)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you. The reason why I am using an old gcc is for compile old programs and linux kernels. But, as you told me, ```-Wall``` looks essential. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

`9223372036854775807` is `0b 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`, this is 1 `0` followed by 63 `1`s (1 bit + 63 bit=64 bit), the leading `0` indicates a positive number in two's complement representation, that is the most common representation of signed integers,
and `9223372036854775807` is also `0b 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111` in the sign + value representation for signed integers when assuming that a positive sign is marked by a `0`-bit.

If a positive sign in the *sign+value representation* of a signed integer is marked by a `1`-bit then `LONG_INT_MAX =9223372036854775807` is actually stored as `0xffff ffff ffff ffff` or `0b1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111` however this would be very uncommon

(https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html?x=9223372036854775807)

There are multiple formats for signed integers, most common is two's complement  for  `-9223372036854775807` (note the (-)-sign) this is `0b1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`, the leading `1` indicates a negative number in two's complement representation

Comment: He basically asks why `LONG_MAX` (9223372036854775807) is stored as `0xffff ffff ffff ffff` and not as `0x7fff ffff ffff ffff`. I'm not sure how this answer helps.

Comment: `LONG_MAX` is NOT stored as `0xffff ffff ffff ffff` because `ffff ffff ffff ffff (hex)` is not even equal to `9223372036854775807 (dec)` you can check this using https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html?x=-9223372036854775807 and this is in this answer ...

Comment: but he somehow found out it is stored as `0xffff ffff ffff ffff`. The problem is we don't know how he found out, and the problem is _there_

Comment: The OP has enhanced the question, and as I supposed, the actual problem was elsewhere (see my answer).

Comment: Re “If a positive sign in the sign+value representation of a signed integer is marked by a 1-bit”: This does not happen in C. Per C 2018 6.2.6.2 2, when the sign bit is zero, the value represented is the same as for an unsigned integer with the same bits.

Comment: Yes i also thought this does not happen and that this is an error ...